# How to create a GitHub repository from multiple local non-git versions

Tags: git, version-control, github, version-control-migration, local-files

Let's say I've been using a small free/open-source code library for a few years, and the project's maintainer/developer does not use any version control system. Instead, new releases are added to a publicly-accessible directory on an ftp server (in other words, the way free software *used to* be distributed). Consequently, I now have a folder on my local machine that contains several versions (i.e., whole copies) of the code library. For example:

```
/foo
    /foo_v0.1.0.zip
    /foo_v0.1.1.zip
    /foo_v0.2.0.zip
    /foo_v1.0.0.zip
    /foo_v1.0.1.zip
    /foo_v1.1.0.zip
    /foo_v2.0.0.zip
```

Now let's say I wanted to convert this into a git repository and push it to a new GitHub repo, such that every version was still individually browse-able/downloadable and I could view each file's diff from one version to the next.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hello Darren, I am not sure if this is the best solution, because I myself am also sort of new to github. But I think each one would have to be its own repository.

Comment: Also if you weren't planning on making changes to them you could probably pack them all into one repository, and then create a new repository for your newest one.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to end up with a history where each version is a commit, yes? You could unzip the oldest version, `git init`, `git add -A`, `git commit -m 'Foo v0.1.0'`. Then delete all the working tree files (perhaps just as easy as `rm -rf *`). Now unzip the next version back into the same folder. Re-add everything (`git add -A`). Commit again. Repeat with each new version.

Comment: As far as making it downloadable from GitHub you could even add some tags on there `git tag 1.0 COMMIT`

Comment: I was hoping someone had already written a script to automate this :)